# Ограничить количество перезагрузок

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть система конроля знаний с помощью тестов. Работает на php,mysql через браузер. Когда пользователь выбирает количество вопросов, предмет тестирования то по отправке формы начинается тестирование на этой странице. Проблема состоит в том, что когда идет тестирование и пользователь не уверен в знании ответов на вопрос, он может перезагрузить страницу и ему загрузятся новые тесты из бд. Как можно избежать перезагрузки и открытия прохождения теста для 1 пользователя 1 раз?

Comment: как вариант записывать номера вопросов пользователю в сессию, и при обновлении если в сессии есть эти айдишники - выводить эти вопросы.

Comment: У вас кто угодно может сделать тест? или зарегистрированные пользователи?

Comment: Только Зарегистрированные